# What are the disadvantages of vh and vw units?

Tags: css, frontend

I am pretty new to front-end development. I wonder what are the disadvantages of vh and vw? I have been always using them because they can adjust the font size based on the screen size. However, I didn't see many people use them as much as I do and saw online that most people prefer to use em. So, it is okay to keep always using vh and vw? What are their disadvantages?

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://docs.elementor.com/article/595-difference-between-px-em-rem-percentage-vw-vh
Read this for more information

Comment: Disadvantage (if you could call it that): Shouldn't be used if you don't want your font size to be tied to the screen size. That's like saying, what are the disadvantages of nails? They shouldn't be used in places where screws should be instead.

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantage is the same as the advantage: it is relative to the *screen dimensions*.

This is something you probably don't want for a font, since "absolute" units like `px` and `cm` already are relative to the perceived size*, which accounts for how distant the observer is from the screen. For example: If a user is using a mobile phone to navigate a web page, you would want the font size to remain constant whether it has a big screen or a small screen.

So I would recommend using an absolute unit like `px` to set the font size, border thicknesses, etc...

---

* According to [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#reference-pixel). In practice, the size of `px` is often synchronized with the OS settings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would you say vh and vw are more often used for divisions?

Comment: Yes, dividing and centering are common use cases.